# Bare expo app crashes with fatal exception in release

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm having the following runtime exception in release mode, I've also tried to disable DexGuard. The application works fine in debug.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
    Process: com.musixmatch.android.lyrify, PID: 14283
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void org.unimodules.core.interfaces.RegistryLifecycleListener.onCreate(org.unimodules.core.ModuleRegistry)"
        at org.unimodules.core.ModuleRegistry.initialize(ModuleRegistry.java:149)
        at org.unimodules.core.ModuleRegistry.ensureIsInitialized(ModuleRegistry.java:131)
        at org.unimodules.adapters.react.ModuleRegistryReadyNotifier.initialize(ModuleRegistryReadyNotifier.java:28)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.doInitialize(ModuleHolder.java:236)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.markInitializable(ModuleHolder.java:100)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceInitialized(NativeModuleRegistry.java:103)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$2.run(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:438)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Don't esitate to ask any question!
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `minSdkVersion` we are using, **21**, is not totally compatible with the set of features used in some expo's unimodules, this, in combination with our very specific build environment and setup, caused the error above.

If you can, upgrading your `minSdkVersion` to version **24** solves the issue.